# c# : How to pass Authorization values as Headers using WebBrowser.Navigate() method?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There is an API which is used to fetch the data from the server, when I pass the whole url with the authorization value it's working fine as below : 
`webBrowser.Navigate("https://abc/resources/1&Authorization=bearer%tokenValue");`

 But as we know its a security leak and not a good practice hence I want to send the authorization details in headers section. 
 Below is the code I tried but couldn't really make it work.

```
string header = "Authorization=bearer tokenValue"
webBrowser.Navigate(https://abc/resources/1, "", null, header);
```

Comment: It's not guaranteed that the server looks to request headers additional to query string. It completely depends to server. But if you are sure the server processes the headers as well, you can send it as the last parameter of `Navigate` method this way: "`Authorization:bearer tokenValue`".

Comment: It works when I pass the url and mention the authorization header in Postman and hence my impression is, it should work with Navigate method too.

Comment: If it works with header, so the only change you need to make is using `:` instead of `=` like first comment.